# Adding a continuously looped video to macOS SwiftUI app

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want to add a few looped videos to a macOS app written in SwiftUI, but when I run it the video doesn't play.

I'm not sure if I've over engineered this or have a bug I can't spot - so hopefully someone can help!

I want call the `VideoTutorialView(videoName:)` passing in a different video.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct VideoTutorialView: View {
    @State private var player = AVQueuePlayer()

    let center = NotificationCenter.default
    let videoName: String

    var body: some View {
        PlayerView(videoName: videoName, player: player)
            .aspectRatio(CGFloat(16 / 9), contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(height: 140)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
            .cornerRadius(.roundedCorner)

            .onAppear { player.play() }
            .onDisappear { player.pause() }
            .onReceive(center.publisher(for: NSApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
                player.pause()
            }
            .onReceive(center.publisher(for: NSApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
                player.play()
            }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct PlayerView: NSViewRepresentable {
    private let videoName: String
    private let player: AVQueuePlayer

    init(videoName: String, player: AVQueuePlayer) {
        self.videoName = videoName
        self.player = player
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {}

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        return LoopingPlayerUIView(videoName: videoName, player: player)
    }
}
```

```swift
class LoopingPlayerUIView: NSView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init(videoName: String,
         player: AVQueuePlayer,
         videoGravity: AVLayerVideoGravity = .resizeAspectFill) {

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoName, withExtension: "mp4") else { return }
        let asset = AVAsset(url: fileUrl)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

        player.isMuted = true
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = videoGravity
        layer?.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: item)
    }

    override func layout() {
        super.layout()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
super.init(frame: .zero)
```

Looks suspicious. You should try setting some values to see the video that are consistent with your SwiftUI view.